# In Powerquery how can i find a text that is not an exact match?

Tags: powerquery

I have the following formula which works and finds an exact match of "1 EA"

```
= List.Select(ColumnNames, each List.Contains(Table.Column(#"Filled Down",_),"1 EA"))
```

However i want to modify it so that it will look for "1 EA" within the text. In other words, if there is text or white space to the left or right, it will still return true

I have tried the following courtsey of ChatGPT but they do not work

```
= List.Select(ColumnNames, each List.AnyTrue(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Filled Down", _), each Text.Contains(_, "1 EA"))))
```

In above i get an error. However there is no description of the error apart from showing the name of a single column which actually contains the "1 EA" text.

```
= List.Select(ColumnNames, each List.Contains(Table.Column(#"Filled Down", _), each Text.Contains(_, "1 EA")))
```

In above i get returned an empty list which also does not make sense

My Data is below- And in below scenario i am expecting to return Data.Column1, Data.Column2 and Data.Column4 as the list:

| Data.Column1 | Data.Column2 | Data.Column3 | Data.Column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample Text | 1 EAsdd | Sample text | 1 EA |
| 1 EA | Sample text | Sample Text | 1 EAff |

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data **as text which can be copy/pasted** so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry have updated. First time on stackoverflow

Comment: The only column that contains `1 EA` is `Date.Column2`. The others do not include the space.

Comment: Updated and corrected the mistake

Comment: See my answer. It works for both but you can easily remove the check without the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data, the following will return the column names of those columns containing `1 EA`. Note that only Column 2 contains that text. If you want to return columns 1,2 and 4, you will need to test for `1EA` as well, as I show in this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Data.Column1", type text}, {"Data.Column2", type text}, {"Data.Column3", type text}, {"Data.Column4", type text}}),

    #"Columns with 1EA" = 
        List.Accumulate(
           Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),
            {},
            (s,c)=> if List.AnyTrue(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Changed Type",c), each 
                Text.Contains(_,"1 EA") or Text.Contains(_, "1EA")))
                        then s & {c} else s)
    
in
    #"Columns with 1EA"
```

***Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

***Edit:**
Given your updated data where you translated `1EA` => `1 EA`, you merely have to change the code to remove the test for `1EA`

```
...
    #"Columns with 1EA" = 
        List.Accumulate(
           Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),
            {},
            (s,c)=> if List.AnyTrue(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Changed Type",c), each 
                Text.Contains(_,"1 EA") ))
                        then s & {c} else s)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```ml
= List.Select(ColumnNames, each Text.Contains(_, "1 EA",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: Thanks PgSystemTester. When i tried it, it is still returning a blank list